# Upload file using Selenium opens windows file explorer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

Ive been struggling for a couple days with this issue,
Im trying to send a file path to a "Upload File" button (not field)

```html
<button type="button" class="browser button button-hero" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;" aria-labelledby="__wp-uploader-id-1 post-upload-info" id="__wp-uploader-id-1">Select files</button>
```

Im using send keys in order to do so but it keeps opening the file explorer. tried everything.
Any ideas? :)

```html
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'upload-ui')]//button[contains(@class, 'button-hero')]").send_keys('C:\\01.png')
```

Comment: Not much we can do without testing the actual url. But I suspect the following: You need to send the file to the first input, 'Select Files', and then you need to click the second button. If it doesn't work, post your url.

Comment: Which input? the attribute is "Button"

Comment: Are there 2 inputs/buttons? One to select the file, second one to click Upload?

Comment: Its the same one, corrected it

Comment: Post your URL, or an identical-behaviour url.

Comment: Im using Wordpress